# Can garbage collection in JBOSS server increase the response time of a request from end user?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, atg, endeca

Recently in site monitoring tool high latency and high response time were reported to production support team,since I just joined this team from JAVA/J2EE background I have nothing much information from where to start from.Few of my team members are saying internal GC of JBOSS(version 5) can increase this response time/site latency.Can any confirm?

Comment: What version of Java?  There have been vast improvements to the incremental GC from version 6 I believe which minimized the stalls caused by full GC's.

Comment: java 6 it is.....

Answer (score 0):

If your JVM memory allocation is not tuned correctly or if you have deployed some recent changes that could result in a memory leak that leads to more Full GC cycles, then yes, Garbage Collection can lead to an increase in site latency.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695874/why-does-the-jvm-full-gc-need-to-stop-the-world) on SO for a description of the 'Stop-The-World' scenario of GC.

Depending on your site monitoring tool, you can look at the frequency of Garbage Collection over time and if after a few hours/days your full GC cycle runs very regularly and pauses for very long, it is definitely a contributing factor to the latency. That said, it is unlikely to be the original cause. For that you need to do some memory profiling and find the potential memory leak or consider allocating more memory to the JVM (which will not really help if there is a memory leak since it will just delay the inevitable)